# incorrect DOUBLE value error

Tags: mysql, database, ionic-framework

I'm currently running into a problem with an UPDATE query. What I'm trying to run is:

```
$sql = "UPDATE nouveauxannonce set An_titre='.$titre.' ,  An_description='.$description.' where id='.$id.'";
```

`$titre`, `$description` and `$id` are sent via a form. I've tried echoing the results and they come out to what I post.

> I recieved :{"_body":"\"ErrorUPDATE nouveauxannonce set
>   An_titre='.dejachanger.' , An_description='.pmiuhbmijlbjn.' where
>   id='.10.'
> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

So can some one please explain what's wrong with my query? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove dots from the query as php replaces only `$var` with variaиle value, not `.$var.`. So it should be like that:

`$sql = "UPDATE nouveauxannonce set An_titre='$titre' ,  An_description='$description' where id='$id'";`

Also consider escaping values that come from youк form, currently you're open to SQL injections.